# Prove distance between a point and an arc is less than the radius

Tags: trigonometry, circles

Given

- a circumference of center A and radius AD
- point P on the X axis with A <= P <= D
- 0 <= angle_alpha <= 90
- C another point on the circumference

How can it be proved that the distance between P and arc CD is always less or equal to the radius?

[image]

Comment: No, it is false, $CP$ can be greater than radius. Think the extreme case when point $C$ is close to the y-axis. So $CP$ is almost like the hypothenus in the triangle $APC$.

Comment: By definition of the distance between a point and a set of points, "*the distance between P and arc CD*" is always $\le PD \le AD$.